Installing llvm-7 on Ubuntu 22.04
I am trying to install llvm-7 on Ubuntu 22.04 Jammy, but cant locate the package with apt-get. The website apt.llvm.org says it itself is deprecated and now I am wondering how I am supposed to install llvm-7.
Thx for your help.
(I require llvm-7 instead of the newer ones, because I am working on a project, which breaks with the newer versions of llvm and I would like to get it running, before I try to update the full project to run on newer versions.)

https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=jammy&arch=any&mode=exactfilename&searchon=contents&keywords=llvm llvm 7 isn't available in the standard Jammy Ubuntu repos

llvm-7 is not available in the default Ubuntu 22.04 repositories. You can install the llvm-7 package from Ubuntu 20.04 in Ubuntu 22.04 by running the following commands:
cd ~/Downloads/
sudo apt update 
wget http://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/universe/l/llvm-toolchain-7/llvm-7_7.0.1-12_amd64.deb http://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/universe/l/llvm-toolchain-7/libllvm7_7.0.1-12_amd64.deb http://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/universe/l/llvm-toolchain-7/llvm-7-runtime_7.0.1-12_amd64.deb  
sudo apt install ./libllvm7_7.0.1-12_amd64.deb ./llvm-7_7.0.1-12_amd64.deb ./llvm-7-runtime_7.0.1-12_amd64.deb

The three packages that wget downloads are llvm-7 and two of its dependency packages.
